# When Compiling a Unity Game for Android, It is still using Android.arch Repo so How do i tell Unity to Use AndroidX

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gradle

Hi I have a Unity Game that I made using Unity 2019 1 . ok  so I installed Android Studio and SDK 28 and I made couple projects with Android Studio just Fine.

So the Unity Game runs fine in Windows when I try to compile for Android I get :

> - What went wrong:
>
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
>
> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradleOut'.
>
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
>
> > **Could not find method implementation() for arguments [{name=android.arch.lifecycle.runtime-1.0.0, ext=aar}] on object of**
> >     type
> >     org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

**So the error I do get it  Unity Is searching for google architecture component lifecycle library from android.arch but Google moved to Androidx repository in Android Studio I would modify gradle module and correct this but how do I do this in Unity ??**